# How can I get the ID of the last INSERTed row using PDO with SQL Server?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2000, pdo

Under other circumstances I might be tempted to use

```
$result = mssql_query("INSERT INTO table (fields) VALUES (data); 
                       SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)");
```

but as I will be inserting user-submitted data, I want to continue to use PDO, which returns an empty array.

Unfortunately, I'm running PHP on a Linux server and using dblib to interface with Microsoft SQL Server, which doesn't support `PDO::lastInsertID()`.

Please help!

**Update to include code example**

Here's the code I'm using: col1 is a field of type `int identity` and col2 is a `datetime` with a default of `getdate()`.

```
//  Connect to db with PDO
$pdo = new PDO( 'dblib:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $database . ';', $username, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION) );
//  Connect to db with MSSQL
$sql = mssql_connect( $host, $username, $password );
mssql_select_db( $database, $sql );
//  Create SQL statement
$query = "INSERT INTO [table] ( col3, col4, col5 )
          VALUES ( 'str1', 'str2', 'str3' );
          SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS theID;";
//  Run with MSSQL
echo "Using MSSQL...\n";
$result = mssql_query( $query );
$the_id = mssql_result( $result, 0, 'theID' );
echo "Query OK. Returned ID is " . $the_id . "\n";
// Run with PDO
echo "\nUsing PDO...\n";
$stmt = $pdo->query( $query );
$result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
print_r( $result );
```

And this is what was displayed:

```
Using MSSQL...
Query OK. Returned ID is 149

Using PDO...
Array
(
)
```

I would love to find out that I'd done something stupid, rather than come up against a horrible dead end :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've got a few choices:

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY - return the last ID created by actions of the current connection, regardless of table/scope

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() - last ID produced by the current connection, in scope, regardless of table

SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('name_of_table'); - last ID produced on that table, regardless of table/scope/connection
```

Of the three, SCOPE_IDENTITY() is the best candidate.

Comment: `PDO` still returns an empty array though. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe try aliasing the results: `SELECT scope_identity() AS id`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm still getting an empty array though. I've updated my question to include the test code I'm using.

Comment: **Update:** I didn't realise the `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` could be sent after the original query. All working now, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are getting two rowsets returned.  Try adding SET NOCOUNT ON; to eliminate the INSERT's rowset, or use $stmt->nextRowset if your driver supports it.