# PDO DBLIB Scope Identity not working

Tags: php, pdo

I'm using DBLIB driver for connecting to a MS SQL server 2008 database from a Linux workstation.

Since DBLIB doesn't support PDO::lastInsertId() method I'm using SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() to get the last inserted id but my code isn't working.

Let's take a look at my code:

```
  function setDataByQuery($query, $values){
    $sth = $this->dbLink->prepare($query);
    $this->bindParams($sth, $values);
    $sth->execute();
    var_dump($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    //$this->lastId = $this->dbLink->lastInsertId();
    return true;
    }
private function bindParams(&$sth, $values){
    $type = array('i'=>PDO::PARAM_INT, 's'=>PDO::PARAM_STR);
    foreach($values as $key=>$value)
        $sth->bindParam($key, $value['data'], $type[$value['type']]);
    }
```

My method setDataByQuery is inserting without problem but when I try to get the last inserted id I get an empty array.

My insertion query looks like this:

```
"INSERT INTO personas (nombres, apellido_paterno, apellido_materno, fecha_nacimiento, sexo, estado_civil, direccion, codigo_postal, id_delegacion, id_empresa)
                VALUES (:n,:aP,:aM,'1900-1-1','H','Unión Libre','Dirección','0000',1,1);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS theID;";
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140529/how-can-i-get-the-id-of-the-last-inserted-row-using-pdo-with-sql-server) question there should be no problem, however the difference is that I'm using prepared queries and that may cause the problem. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason this wasn't working when both statements where in the same query so I created another function which did the job.

```
function setDataByQuery($query, $values){
    $sth = $this->dbLink->prepare($query);
    $this->bindParams($sth, $values);
    if(!$sth->execute())
            return false;
    $this->lastId = $this->lastInsertId();
    //$this->lastId = $this->dbLink->lastInsertId();
    return true;
    }
 private function lastInsertId($seqname = null){
    $sth = $this->dbLink->prepare('SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS id');
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetch();
    return $result['id'];
    }
```

Comment: I'm with the same problem, and I need do it, but I'm using laravel 5, and I don't wanna change the framework code. Do you have any idea of how can I change it on the laravel without change the framework code?